# Programatically check which android theme is active

Tags: android, themes

Is there any way to check during runtime which android theme is active?

For example

```
if(getThemeId==R.style.theme_to_check){
    //Some action based on which theme is active
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current theme ressource id with this :

```
private int getThemeResId() {
    try {
        Method method = Context.class.getMethod("getThemeResId");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (Integer) method.invoke(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this works, it appears this is accessing private members.  I'm hesitant to use this since it appears getting the current context theme id isn't a supported operation by the Android library.